# How to find solution for this equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, lambert-w

I have following equation$$x\ln(1+\frac{b}{x})=b$$

where $b>0$. How to find the solution for $x$. I know how to solve equation involving $x\ln(x)$ but I don't know how to solve equation where inverse of $x$ is present.

Any help in this regard will be much appreciated.

BR

Frank

Comment: First of all, divide it by $x$ and denote $b/x$ by a new variable.

Comment: yes i did it but then i get inverse at the outside of logrithm

Comment: @AndrewMiloradovsky BTW what will be the next step can you elaborate it a bit. Thanks

Comment: I do not believe there is a real valued solution for $x$ if you take $b > 0$.

Comment: It seems like there is no finite solutions for $x$. Because $y = x'$ lays above $y = \log(1 + x')$ everywhere except $x' = 0$, and, if $x' = b / x$, it means $x = \infty$.

Comment: $\ln {(1+t)} \le t$, when $t=0$ get "=". so you don't have solution for $x$ unless $b=0$

Answer (score 1):

$$\ln(1+u)=u\implies u=0.$$
You can simply show that $u\longmapsto \ln(1+u)-u$ is strictly decreasing on $[0,\infty [$ to have the unicity.

Answer (score 1):

Transform

$$\ln\left(1+\frac{b}{x}\right)=\frac{b}{x},$$
$$\ln\left(1+\frac{b}{x}\right)-\left(1+\frac{b}{x}\right)=1,$$

$$-\left(1+\frac{b}{x}\right)e^{-\left(1+\frac{b}{x}\right)}=-e,$$

$$-\left(1+\frac{b}{x}\right)=W(-e).$$

---

Looking for a complex solution, let

$$\ln(z)=z-1,$$ or in polar coordinates

$$\ln(r)+i\theta=r\cos(\theta)+ir\sin(\theta)-1,$$

giving

$$r=\frac\theta{\sin(\theta)},\\
\ln\left(\frac\theta{\sin(\theta)}\right)=\theta\cot(\theta)-1.$$

The first nontrivial solution is found numerically as

$$\theta=1.7881880413836\cdots,\\r=1.8312905141248\cdots,\\z=-0.3949790827072\cdots+i 1.7881880413836\cdots$$

Comment: So, no real solutions, I guess.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: quite right.